# Highlight difference in two structures

Tags: .net, wpf

I have structures like this

```
class Experiment
{
    Result Result1 {get; set;}
    Result Result2 {get; set;}
}

class Result
{
    int Param1;
    double Param2;
    ...
}
```

In XAML I have control which can represent Result class.
Binding looks like this

```
     <CalculationResultsControl DataContext="{Binding VM.SelectedExperiment.Result1}"/>
     <CalculationResultsControl DataContext="{Binding VM.SelectedExperiment.Result2}"/>
```

I want to show difference in Result2 compared to Result1.
For example, if Param2 is different for Result1 and Result2 I want to mark this value with red color.

How can I do it in automatic way? Should I write code behind trigger? How?

Comment: What control represent this data in XAML?

Comment: CalculationResultsControl. Sorry, I pasted code in the wrong place. Post was updated.

Comment: So in case value is different you want to set Background of this control `Red`?

Comment: Yes. And I cannot/don't want to modify Result data structures.